# Splitting field in multiple field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, proof-writing, splitting-field

Let $F\subset K\subset E$ be fields, $f(x)\in F[x]$. E is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$. Prove $E$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$.

My problem with this proof is that I do not know how to write it. I understand the idea, but what is the most efficient way to express it?

This was what I came up with: Assume that E is not the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $K$. Then that contradicts by the definition of splitting field.

Is that right conceptually, or do I not understand this? Thanks for any comments or help

Comment: The sentence beginning "Then that means ..." is wrong. In fact it is self-contradictory!

Comment: You can't just say "that contradicts" without saying *what* it contradicts.

Comment: I said the sentence was self-contradictory, which means that if contains two statements that contradict each other. The offending sentence has gone now, but it would have been better if it had been replaced by a correct sentence. (There was and "and" that should have been "or".)

Comment: @DerekHolt: Can I just contradict this by the definition of the splitting field though?

Comment: Yes, but you have to write down the proof. At the moment you haven't done. There are two things you have to show: (i) $E$ contains all roots of $f$ regarded as a polynomial in $K[x]$; and (ii) no proper subfield of $E$ that contains $K$ contains all of these roots. They are not hard to prove, but you have to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $E$ is *not* the smallest field containing $K$ and the roots of $f$. Then there is such a field and it is smaller than $E$, say $M$. Now $M$ is a field containing $F$ and the roots of $f$ and is $\subsetneq E$ ...